# How can I adapt my working tensorflow model to use bidirectional LSTM?

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, one-hot-encoding

At the moment I have a model that achieves around 81% accuracy. The data that I am working with is sequential, so I would like to try and include a bidirectional LSTM layer to see if this can boost the performance a bit.

My data is sequences of letters, e.g. `ABCD`. To pass sequences through my model, I use one-hot encoding. So `ABCD` might become:

```
[ [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0] ]
```

Note - Sequences are actually 300 characters long, but I wanted to keep the previous example simple for the sake of the question.

So at the moment my model looks like this:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(300, 6)),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='tanh'),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='tanh'),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])
```

So the input shape shows that each sequence is 300 letters long, with 6 letters to choose from. This model works.

Now I want to adapt my model to use a bidirectional LSTM layer, as I understand this may give me better performance with sequential data. However, I'm struggling to understand how I can adapt this model to achieve this. I've tried various different arrangements of layers, but I'm getting errors relating to dimensionality.

I want something *like* the following:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(300, 6)),
    keras.layers.Bidirectional(LSTM(64)),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='tanh'),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='tanh'),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])
```

I'm hoping someone with a better understanding of bidirectional LSTM might be able to offer some guidance on how to do this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Remove `Flatten`.

Once you do the `Flatten` layer, your input loses the sequential structure. It turns the shape *b* × 300 × 6 into *b* × 1800 where *b* is your batch size. Every training example is represented by a 1800-dimensional vector, there is no dimension, the LSTM would iterate on.

I would also consider replacing the `tanh` activations with `relu`, so you at least partially avoid the vanishing gradients.